# How to logrotate with systemd?

Tags: systemd, logrotate

I'm running a node app using systemd with a unit file. The apps log can be viewed using `journalctl -u example.com` but the log gets cut at some point, erasing the history (which I need for debugging).

How do I configure log rotation with systemd so that my app logs gets stored in `example.com.log.1`, `example.com.log.2` etc. so I can query the history of my app?

This is my unit file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node keystone.js
#Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=example.com
User=user
Group=user
Environment=NODE_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Please include your systemd version as well as your OS and version.

Comment: Review `man journald.conf` to review options controlling disk space of the systemd journal. If you still have a question, post the contents of your `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Increasing Storage**

If you are storing to disk you can increase the amount of space used by changing `SystemMaxUse` and/or `SystemKeepFree`. Having more space would allow more entries to be stored.

By default the maximum use limit (`SystemMaxUse`) is 10% of the filesystem, and the minimum free space (`SystemKeepFree`) value is 15% - though they are both capped at 4G.

**Journal Rotation**

The journals should be rotated automatically when they reach the `SystemMaxFileSize` value, and the number of journals is controlled by `SystemMaxFiles`. If you prefer time based rotation you can set a `MaxFileSec` to set the maximum time entries are stored in a single journal.

**Note on Storage Location/Type**

With journald you can choose to store the journal entries either in memory (`Storage=volatile`) or on disk (`Storage=persistent`). The above assumes you are storing journals on disk - if this is not the case "System" will need to be replaced by "Runtime" in the above variables.

Further details are available in `man journald.conf`.

***Alternative - Passing on the journal entries***

If you are already familiar with the traditional SYSLOG daemon you can pass the journal events on by setting the `ForwardToSyslog` option (which forwards the messages immediately) or have the syslog daemon behave like a journal client and fetch the logs itself.